# Undefined index: user in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

i have following array which is generated from my object

```
Laravel\Socialite\Two\User Object
(
    [token] => some token valuw
    [id] => 12345567769667
    [nickname] => 
    [name] => user name
    [email] => username@test.com

    [user] => Array
        (
            [kind] => plus

            [gender] => male
            [emails] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => username@test.com
                            [type] => account
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

if i try to access id nickname,name,email like

```
echo $user->id;
```

it display output.
if i try to access

```
echo $user->user->gender;
```

or

```
echo $user['user']['gender'];
```

then it throw error as `undefined index user`

how i can access gender and email value ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 echo $user->user['gender'];
```

To access email value:

```
$emailVal = [];
foreach($user->user['emails'] as $key => $val) {
  $emailVal[] = ['value' => $val['value'], 'type' => $val['type']];
}

print_r($emailVal);
```

Or if you want to access only email:

```
 echo $user->user['emails'][0]['value'];
```

Comment: @tester. Kindly accept my answer if it works. Thank you

Comment: ya sure.now i have to wait for 11 min after asking question.so waiting to accept

Comment: how to access email value ?

Comment: You need to `foreach` loop. I'll add that in my answer

Comment: thank you.only small correction in your answer.foreach($user->user['emails'] as $key=>$val)

Comment: @tester Yeah. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

`$user` is an `object` and `user` is an `array`

```
if (property_exists($user, user) && !empty($user->user[gender])) {
  $user->user[gender]; // to access gender
  $user->user[emails]; // to access email
}
```

to avoid notices and warnings